# PHP (Wordpress) on App Engine: gethostbyname failed

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have been following the instructions in the App Engine article "[Running WordPress in App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress)". Particularly on the Dashboard, I keep getting the following errors:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0 in /base/data/home/apps/s~lean-writing-001/19.375206187980701020/wordpress/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 895
Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://api.wordpress.org:80 (php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0) in /base/data/home/apps/s~lean-writing-001/19.375206187980701020/wordpress/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 895
```

I infer from the context of the code that WordPress likes to phone home to check for updates, but I would think that Google's App Engine DNS would resolve their host name.

Yes, I could replace all occurrences of "api.wordpress.org" with one of it's round-robin IP addresses, but I am loathe to hack the WordPress code like that. It's not reliable, and it looks like there are 18 such occurrences.

Is this a red herring for another problem I should be looking for? Did I miss a key step in the above-referenced article?

Comment: Sockets API is only available for paid apps. Do you have billing activated? Also see this for more info: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/

Comment: I'm paying for the Cloud project and my credit card is getting billed for it.

I saw error messages (about activating billing) in the App Engine log, but I could find no switch on the console to activate or deactivate billing.

Comment: It seems to be a billing issue. Could you check the "Billing Status" section for your project in the admin console: https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: I see no "Billing Status" section at appengine.google.com. I've been using https://console.developers.google.com. Under /billing/<ProjectNumber>/settings, it shows that my credit card will be (and it has been) billed monthly.

Comment: Found it. https://appengine.google.com/billing/billing_status. Apparently App Engine billing does not roll into Google Cloud Platform billing. That is REALLY broken.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project

Click on your project, then click 'Billing' in the left column.

Comment: Did that weeks ago. Billing for the project is still active.

I wonder if my trouble is because I took advantage of a Compute Engine promotional offer for that project, and it's interfering with App Engine billing. I have that question pending with Google now.

Comment: I recommend using the wordpress project already configured for appengine instead. http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

Comment: Tried that. Same results.